# Why is ArrayList RandomAccess but ArrayDeque not?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, deque

Well, we know that  [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) is a marker interface, and the documentation says:

> Marker interface used by List implementations to indicate that they support fast (generally constant time) random access. The primary purpose of this interface is to allow generic algorithms to alter their behaviour to provide good performance when applied to either random or sequential access lists.

Thus, it makes total sense to me that `ArrayList` implements `RandomAccess` interface as internally elements are stored in an array, which can be randomly accessed. However, if you will see the internal implementation of [`ArrayDeque`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayDeque.java?av=f) which also stores elements in an array, but it does not implements `RandomAccess`, was it intended or it was done some explicit reason *which I am not aware of*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RandomAccess` is used by `List` implementations to indicate they support fast random access.

`ArrayDeque` isn't a `List` and doesn't have any random access methods (there are no index-based `add`, `get`, `remove` or `set` methods), so having it be `RandomAccess` wouldn't make sense.

The underlying structure might be random access, but the class doesn't allow random access.

Comment: That answered my question. Thanks.